# If $X$ and $X'$ are two products in a category $\mathcal{C}$, then is there a unique isomorphism between them?

Tags: category-theory

I've shown that they are in fact isomorphic. But I don't see how to show that the isomorphism that exists is unique.

Also, what if we are given two coproducts? Is then the isomorphism unique?

Comment: There are infinitely many automorphisms of $\Bbb{R}^2$ (here $C$ is the category of $\Bbb{R}$-vector spaces). Now, let $X=X'=\Bbb{R}^2 = \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$: it is not true that there is a unique isomorphism between them.

Comment: There may be more than one isomorphism, but there is only one isomorphism that preserves the projections.

Comment: @MattSamuel Is this also true in the case of coproducts?

Comment: @Maria For coproducts, instead of the projections it would be the canonical maps into the coproduct. Universal constructions generally have this property; there is a unique isomorphism preserving whatever baggage it comes with.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks so much.

Comment: @Maria No problem.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Just to be clear, you meant in the coproduct case also the isomorphism that preserves the canonical injections is unique, not that it is the only isomorphism?

Comment: @Maria Right. There's no claim that it's the only isomorphism without any restrictions.